# Ordering file http stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, stream, streaming

I'm streaming a video over a http connection, using a nodeJS server.

At the moment, I'm reading chunks from the video before writing the each chunk to the stream, sequentially; thus, very slowly.

I want to pipeline this, so I'm multiple asynchronous requests for data, thus, increasing my throughput.

But, the data I request will not arrive in order, so I cant simply relay the chunks to the HTTP stream as I was before.

I believe I will need to buffer the data until I have the next peice(s) to be written, in order. However, I also believe this will use much more memory, because I the application will be storing multiple chunks on behalf of the user.

Is it possible to have the client sort the chunks, some how, so I can instantly relay it in an unordered fashion (with a chunk-id), allowing me to resume minimal memory usage?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a causal RTP algorithm, you could read about Saul E. Pomares Hernandez, Eduardo Lopez Dominguez works, they have some good papers about this subject, they both are researcher from INAOE University.

Enjoy it!

Comment: I can't do this over HTTP right? I'll need like a websocket. How, then, could I reconstruct the file/build it live, the video is being played back, thus needs to be accessible by HTML video element as url.